# How to convert .cs file to a PowerShell cmdlet?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Can anyone help me to convert a C# .NET program to PowerShell cmdlet? I am very new to this area. Please help me to get out of this checkpoint!

Regards,

Arun

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methods to convert C# code to a PowerShell Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143460/methods-to-convert-c-sharp-code-to-a-powershell-script)

Answer (score 13):

Add a reference to *System.Management.Automation*, create a class that inherits from *Cmdlet* and override the *ProcessRecord* method:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Double")]
public class GetDouble : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter]
    public int SomeInput { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        WriteObject(SomeInput * 2);
    }
}
```

Add an installer:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MySnapin : PSSnapIn
{
    public override string Name { get { return "MyCommandlets"; } }
    public override string Vendor { get { return "MyCompany"; } }
    public override string Description { get { return "Does unnecessary aritmetic."; } }
}
```

Install your commandlet assembly:

```
Installutil /i myassembly.dll
```

And add:

```
Add-PsSnapin MyCommandlets
```

Comment: FYI: System.Management.Automation can be referenced after installing the Reference Assemblies from the Windows SDK.

Comment: great tip. also great answer this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should convert your .cs file into a DLL using PowerShell template. Then by using `pssnapin` and `getproc` you can convert it into a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

There's an add-on for Reflector to do that.
Here's a good article with the example: http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2009/09/18/powershell-for-the-net-developer.aspx*

> .NET Reflector has [an array of add-ons on CodePlex](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/releases/view/1805), and one of these
>   is [the PowerShell add-on](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PowerShellLanguage&ProjectName=reflectoraddins) that allows you to disassemble code directly
>   into PowerShell.
>
> In this example, I am opening the method ChangeAccountPassword from
>   the SPUtility library in SharePoint:
>
> [image]
>
> I can now change targets from C# to PowerShell.
>
> [image]
>
> When you need to convert helper methods from C# to PowerShell or if
>   you’re new to PowerShell syntax, this tool is really helpful!

[*] The link is dead as of 10/12/2015.

Comment: Link is dead. Here's a summarizing article: https://blog.lekman.com/2011/10/converting-c-to-powershell.html

Comment: @Zachafer Thank you, pasted the article by your link into the answer in case that one dies as well.