# How to convert C# code to a PowerShell Script?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I regularly have to convert an existing C# code snippet/.CS file to a PowerShell script.  How could I automate this process?

While I am aware that there are methods that can [convert a .cs file to a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343182/how-to-convert-cs-file-to-a-powershell-cmdlet), I'm only interested in converting the C# code to a script or module.

Comment: here's a paid product  https://docs.poshtools.com/powershell-tools-documentation/visual-studio/code-conversion

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I know you're looking for something that somehow converts C# directly to PowerShell, but I thought this is close enough to suggest it.

In PS v1 you can use a compiled .NET DLL:

```
PS> $client = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
PS> $client.Connect($address, $port)
```

In PS v2 you can add C# code directly into PowerShell and use it without 'converting' using Add-Type (copied straight from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315241.aspx) )

```
C:\PS>$source = @"
public class BasicTest
{
    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }

    public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a * b);
    }
}
"@

C:\PS> Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source

C:\PS> [BasicTest]::Add(4, 3)

C:\PS> $basicTestObject = New-Object BasicTest 
C:\PS> $basicTestObject.Multiply(5, 2)
```

Comment: Can I use my custom libraries C# with helpers and utils class?

Comment: How to get .Netframework support in PowerShell?  Will this work on just a brand new machine imaged with windows without .netframework installed?  

How to get .net framework support in a powershell?

Answer (score 12):

There is a [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) [add-in for PowerShell](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PowerShellLanguage&referringTitle=Home) that will allow you to see the corresponding PowerShell script for static methods on classes

There's a good post with the example: http://blogs.msmvps.com/paulomorgado/2009/09/17/powershell-for-the-net-developer/.

Answer (score 1):

[PowerShell Pro Tools](https://docs.poshtools.com/powershell-pro-tools-documentation/visual-studio/code-conversion) for Visual Studio have a feature to convert C# code in a PowerShell script.