# TotalCount command in powershell

Tags: powershell, record, db2-content-manager

Is it possible to get the total count of records in db (5M records) using powershell?

```
$database = New-Object HP.HPTRIM.SDK.Database
$database.Id = "10"
$database.WorkgroupServerName = "dbnonprod"
$database.Connect() 
$recordSearch = New-Object HP.HPTRIM.SDK.TrimMainObjectSearch($database, [HP.HPTRIM.SDK.BaseObjectTypes]::Record)
$recordSearch.SetsearchString("All")

$a = 0

foreach ($record in $recordSearch) {
$a+= $record.count
}
echo $a
```

And this is my error when trying to get the totalcount store on the db from content manager database

> Content Manager Workgroup Server on 'dbnonprod' reported an error.
> Could not serialize the server-side recordset. Error with SQL
> Connection: The ODBC connection is not active any more, could be
> forcibly closed by the server or in load balancing.

Comment: I don't have a HPTrim to test with, but look at [search](https://content-manager-sdk.github.io/Community/91/programming_guide.html#Searching_for_HPE_Records_Manager_objects) and its [count](https://content-manager-sdk.github.io/Community/91/class_h_p_1_1_h_p_t_r_i_m_1_1_s_d_k_1_1_trim_main_object_search.html#a2f478a8c30d8c57f8c22388be5b963ab) method, which should return you the object count instead of iterating the result set.

Comment: The SDK and PowerShell have different code.

Comment: Yes, because the SDK samples are C#. Conversion to Powershell is usually [quite simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143945/503046), and if that fails, one can embed C# into PS code too.

Comment: How should I integrate this code? HP.HPTRIM.SDK.TrimMainObjectSearch.FastCount.
To prevent the connection from being disconnected.